# Why "class" as key included in JSON?

Tags: java, json

I am trying to create a JSON object but getting a "class" key in JSON object.

I am using [this](http://www.json.org/java/index.html) library.

Below is the code I am using.

```
    //Class being used for JSON conversion.
package com.test;
    public class Sample {

        public String name;

        public String surname;



        public Sample(String name, String surname) {
            this.name = name;
            this.surname = surname;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public String getSurname() {
            return surname;
        }


    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
    Sample sample = new Sample("Sam", "Sammy");
    System.out.println(new JSONObject(sample));

    }
```

I am getting the json as:

```
{"class":"class com.test.Sample","surname":"Sammy","name":"Sam"}
```

Comment: org.json is not the best if you want to do {de,}serialization; I'd recommend using Jackson (others may recommend Gson).

Comment: @fge But can you please point out what is the problem here?

Comment: See my answer... Probably a bug in org.json! Use another library ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick way to do it: [Remove](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#remove%28java.lang.String%29) the class attribute.

```
JSonObject obj = new JSONObject(sample);
obj.remove("class");
System.out.println(obj);
```

Answer (score 5):

The [constructor you are using](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject%28java.lang.Object%29) is described as such (emphasis mine):

> Construct a JSONObject from an Object using bean getters. **It reflects on all of the public methods of the object**. For each of the methods with no parameters and a name starting with "get" or "is" followed by an uppercase letter, the method is invoked, and a key and the value returned from the getter method are put into the new JSONObject. The key is formed by removing the "get" or "is" prefix. If the second remaining character is not upper case, then the first character is converted to lower case. For example, if an object has a method named "getName", and if the result of calling object.getName() is "Larry Fine", then the JSONObject will contain "name": "Larry Fine".

Looks like this constructor does not make an exception for `.getClass()`, which is `public` in `Object` ;)

Comment: If you look at the source https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java/blob/master/JSONObject.java , it does compare if ("getClass".equals(name)
                                || "getDeclaringClass".equals(name)) {
                            key = "";
                        }

Comment: Well, it appears you don't have a version with that code, then